# tilemap flickering on update

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, dictionary, tile

Im trying to draw a game map to a canvas using a JSON file created by tiled map editor.

I believe im nearly there, but i have one problem. if i put the call to load the map in my update function i get the map flickering in the canvas. I guess this is because i am clearing the canvas each update.

So if i move the call to load the scene anywhere else in the main js file like the game_settings function (which is where i want it) i just get a blank canvas.

Here is my main js file:

```
var canvas;
var ctx;

$(document).ready(function(){

canvas = document.getElementById("TBG");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var game_width = canvas.width;
var game_height = canvas.height;

var scene = new Scene();


$('#new_but').click(function(){
    game_init("new");
});

$('#load_but').click(function(){
    game_init("load");
});


function game_init(state) {
    game_settings(state);
    update();
}

function game_settings(state){
    if(state == "load"){
        ui.load_game();

    }
    else{
        //set beginning params
        ui.new_game();
    }
}


function update(){

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    scene.load("level_01");

    setTimeout(update,1);
}
});
```

My question: where should i be calling the scene.load method??

If yo would like to see the scene class file it is [here](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:31c0)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem about tilemap flickering is not caused by canvas clearing but for the

```
scene.load();
```

called every time in the

> update()

It needs some time to load the tile, so during the tile loading the canvas will be blank(because the *"ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);"* has been called), and after the tile loaded the canvas will be filled again. So you will see the flickering effect.
Two methods will be helpful to sovle this problem:

1. Do not clear the canvas untill the new tile is loaded and
2. Local store the tiles have been loaded.

These can avoid the flickering problem, and hope that will be helpfut to you.